# image is not uploading in YII ActiveForm

Tags: php, file, yii2

I am new to Yii. I am using this code

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput(['type' => 'file']) ?>

    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

When i try to print post data in my controller then image field is going blank;
If i print through

```
 $_FILES
```

then file data is showing. 

Please let me know how to get image in post method.

Comment: Use [getInstance()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstance%28%29-detail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create `UploadForm` model

   ```
   namespace app\models;
   use yii\base\Model;
   use yii\web\UploadedFile;
   class UploadForm extends Model{
       public $image;// Image name 
       public function rules()
       {
           return [
               [['image'], 'file'/* , 'skipOnEmpty' => false *//* , 'extensions' => 'png, jpg' */],
           ];
       }    
       public function upload($fileName)
       {
           if ($this->validate()) {
               $this->image->saveAs($fileName);
               return true;
           } else {
               return false;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Controller code
   Add at top of your file

   ```
   use app\models\UploadForm;
   use yii\web\UploadedFile;
   ```

   Add this in your function

   ```
   $model = User();
   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
       $model1 = new UploadForm();

   $model1->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

   $fileName  = $model1->image->baseName.'_'.time();
   $extension = $model1->image->extension;

   $fileName   =   $fileName.'.'.$extension;
   $filePath   =   WEBSITE_SLIDER_ROOT_PATH.$fileName;     
   if ($model1->upload($filePath)) {
       //Save in database
   }   


   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 : 
In your model file define one variable.

```
public $uploadedImage;
```

Step 2 : 
In your controller,

```
$model->uploadedImage = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
$model->image = $model->uploadedImage->name;
```

After save() method write this to store image

```
$model->uploadedImage->saveAs('YOUR_WEBDIR_IMAGES_FOLDER/' . $model->uploadedImage->baseName . '.' . $model->uploadedImage->extension);
```

[If the above solution doesn't work then try this. :

Define another variable.

```
public $tempVarforImage;
```

In your controller

```
$model->tempVarforImage = $model->uploadedImage->name;
$model->image = $model->tempVarforImage;
```

(Because once I faced the issue in confliction of 'image' field from database and yii2 based 'image' variable)]

Comment: Also check permissions for the YOUR_WEBDIR_IMAGES_FOLDER folder